# Oauth 2.0 request with Axios failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm able to interface with the Yahoo Fantasy API using Oauth 2.0 in PHP, but when I try to convert my code into JavaScript using Axios HTTP request library, I get no response. What am I doing wrong?

First, here's the working, valid PHP version:

```
function refreshAuthorizationToken($token) {

    $consumer_key = "consumerKeyGoesHere";
    $consumer_secret = "myConsumerSecretGoesHere";
    $auth_header = base64_encode($consumer_key . ":" . $consumer_secret);
    $auth_endpoint = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token";

    $ch = curl_init();

    $post_values = [
        "redirect_uri" => "oob",
        "grant_type" => "refresh_token",
        "refresh_token" => $token
    ];

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $auth_endpoint,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Basic ' . $auth_header,
        'Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36'),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post_values)
    ));

    $answer = curl_exec($ch);
    $token = json_decode($answer);

    if (!isset($access_token)) {
        return "Error: access token not set."

    }
    else {
        return $token;
    }
}
```

Now here's the JavaScript code that's not working:

```js
const consumerKey = `consumerKeyGoesHere`;
const consumerSecret = `consumerSecretGoesHere`;
const authHeader = Buffer.from(`${consumerKey}:${consumerSecret}`, `binary`).toString(`base64`);

async function refreshAuthorizationToken(token) {
    const authEndpoint = `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token`;

    let response;
    try {
        response = await axios({
            url: authEndpoint,
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'Authorization': `Basic ${authHeader}`,
              'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'authorization',
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36',
            },
            data: {
              redirect_uri: 'oob',
              grant_type: 'refresh_token',
              refresh_token: token
            },
            timeout: 1000,
          });
          if (response.data) writeToFile(response.data, authFile, 'w');
          return JSON.parse(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error in refreshAuthorizationToken: ${error}`);
    }
}
```

I've tried `params` instead of `data` but no matter what this request just dies with no response no matter how I try to catch errors (tried a few different permutations).

I thought maybe this was an HTTPS issue, but even if I create an HTTPS server with a self-signed certificate the request still dies silently.

Any idea how to fix this? Or examples of a properly formed OAuth 2.0 client refresh token request using Axios/Node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two problems -- one, as [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) pointed out below, I needed to stringify the data JSON if I'm going to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (which the Yahoo API requires).

The second problem was my promise handling. `refreshAuthorizationToken` should not be async nor use await, it should just return axios -- it's the *calling* function that should use async/await.

The working code:

```
const qs = require('qs');
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');

const consumerKey = `myConsumerKeyHere`;
const consumerSecret = `myConsumerSecretHere`;
const authHeader = Buffer.from(`${consumerKey}:${consumerSecret}`, `binary`).toString(`base64`);
const authEndpoint = `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token`;


function writeToFile(data, file, flag) {
    if (flag === null) flag = `a`;
    fs.writeFile(file, data, {flag: flag}, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(`Error in writing to ${file}: ${err}`);
        }
    });
}

function refreshAuthorizationToken(token) {

    return axios({
        url: authEndpoint,
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${authHeader}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36',
        },
        data: qs.stringify({
            redirect_uri: 'oob',
            grant_type: 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token: token
        }),
        timeout: 1000,
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(`Some kind of horrible error in refreshAuthorizationToken: ${error}`);
    });

}

async function reload() {
    const returnVal = await refreshAuthorizationToken(credentials.refresh_token); 
    if (returnVal) {
        if (returnVal.data && returnVal.data.access_token) {
            writeToFile(JSON.stringify(returnVal.data), authFile, 'w');
        }
    }
}

reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format) for axios:

> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To send data in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead, you can use one of the following options.

You are setting a `Content-Type` header which claims you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, but you haven't done any of the things that the documentation suggests to generate data in that format.

---

Aside:

```
'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'authorization',
```

That's a *response* header, it makes no sense to include it on the request.

Comment: Changing to `application/json` has no effect, nor does using `qs.stringify` with form-encoded. any other ideas?